# Build API Gateway on AWS using Terraform returning statusCode 200

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I am a noob also doesn't know how to ask questions,
actually i want to create a API Gateway using TF that should returning statusCode 200, i tried offical TF examples to create one but the API Gateway return 500 instead of 200, i can't able to figure out what is the error, you can look at my code below , it doesn't using lambda or anything , i just tried with mock endpoint but still can't able to figure out

**TF CODE**

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "MyDemoAPI" {
  name        = "MyDemoAPI"
  description = "This is my API for demonstration purposes"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "MyDemoResource" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "mydemoresource"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "MyDemoMethod" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource.id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "MyDemoIntegration" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.MyDemoMethod.http_method
  type        = "MOCK"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.MyDemoMethod.http_method
  status_code = "200"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "MyDemoIntegrationResponse" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.MyDemoMethod.http_method
  status_code = aws_api_gateway_method_response.response_200.status_code

  # Transforms the backend JSON response to XML
  response_templates = {
    "application/xml" = <<EOF
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>
    $inputRoot.body
</message>
EOF
  }
}
```

When i created one in AWS console it's working fine, but i can't able to do that using this TF code

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have't specified `request_templates` for your `MyDemoIntegration`:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "MyDemoIntegration" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.MyDemoMethod.http_method
  type        = "MOCK"
  
  request_templates = {
    "application/json" = <<EOF
{
   "statusCode": 200
}
EOF
  }  
}
```